# Navigation List Drawer not a ListView?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've just begun playing with Android's new navigation drawer. Is it possible to have a custom view (specifically custom `ScrollView`) instead of the `ListView` in the drawer? I've been running into errors trying to get this up and running.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to have a custom view (specifically custom ScrollView) instead of the ListView in the drawer?

Anything should work. In terms of UI style, though, users will be expecting something that resembles a `ListView` or `ExpandableListView`.

Comment: I can't get and expandablelistview child click to close the navigation drawer is it possible ?

Comment: @prateek: I have no idea.

Comment: Its ok. I got the answer to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you .

[This will help you implement Expandable ListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview_concept)

and i your main activity change the following :

```
MyExpandableList adapter = new MyExpandableList(this, groups);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```